# Update states on click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to update Status in MYSQL with click on this SPAN.

```
$_a = array();
 if(isset($naval['a'])){
 foreach($naval['a'] as $a){
     $_a[] = '<b><span class="badge '.(($a['status'] == 0)?'red':'green').'">'.date('d.m', $a['date']).'</span></b>';
}
```

}

Tabele Format
TablenameA -> Columns: ID, data, status, tipe

How te modify in realtime with on single click the STATUS?
Thanks

Comment: Try 
http://api.jquery.com/load/ with this http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Can add  `data-` attributes to element

`'<span data-id="'.$a['ID'].'" data-status="'.$a['status'].'" class......'`

Then use ajax to send data to server when clicked:

```
$('.badge').click(function(){
  var data={
      id: $(this).data('id'),
      status: $(this).data('status')
  }

   $.post('path/to/server/file', data, function(response){
       /* do something with response, and/or modify element*/
   })

})
```

Comment: Is not working, in same page i have 10 to 200 spans with class="badge

Comment: what's not workng? If it's because `badge` is too generic...give the ones that need `click` a class and use that class for selector